# Select all occurrences of the current word in this block

Tags: visual-studio-code

If I have the following, and want to refactor it by renaming `a` in `test2`, is there a good way to select all occurrences within that scope only? At the moment, I usually use `ctrl+d` until I am at the end of my block, but that is error-prone and tiring.

```
void test1() {
const int a = 5;
return a;
}

void test2(int a) {
std::cout<< a << std::endl;
}

void test3() {
const int a = 5;
return a;
}
```

Comment: Try the `Rename SYmbol` option in the context menu after you have selected the symbol.  This action would be supplied by the file's language extension, so see if it is supported in this file.

Answer (score 0):

- place the cursor on the variable `a`
- press `F2`
- rename it to something unique like `XXYYZZ`
- place the cursor on the variable `XXYYZZ`
- press `Ctrl+D` to select it
- use `Ctrl+Shift+L` to select all `XXYYZZ`

If you need to do this often you can place this into a key binding with the command `runCommands` if the command for rename variable accepts arguments.